# Trigger a Batch file from UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shell, user-interface, batch-file

If I have a bat file in user's machine, How can I run the bat file in chrome using JavaScript or something else? I could do it in IE browser through ActiveXObject, However this object is not applicable for chrome or firefox.

Comment: You can't, Most browsers wont allow it due to how much of a security risk it is.

Answer (score 1):

Due to security concerns this sort of activity is blocked in modern browsers. The [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) can perform other file operations, but is mostly sandboxed.

Comment: Is there any alternative solution to trigger a batch file from UI.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this batch file?

Comment: hey, I am trying to execute a jar which is locally stored.

Comment: That isn't possible unfortunately, but I may be able to suggest an alternative to achieve the same functionality. What is the end result that you're hoping to get by executing this jar?